# Anything like a static delegatecall from a view function?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, delegatecall

let's say there are two contracts A and B, where A calls methods in B. I understand that A can modify and read storage in B with B.call() and B.staticcall(), ie. A can execute B's methods in the context of B. For example:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract A {

    address _sub = address(B);

    function write(uint256 _a) public returns (bool, bytes memory) {
        (bool x, bytes memory y) = _sub.call(msg.data);
        return (x, y);
    }

    function read(uint256 _b) public view returns (bool, bytes memory) {
        (bool x, bytes memory y) = _sub.staticcall(msg.data);
        return (x, y);
    }
}
```

and

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract B {
    mapping (uint256 => bool) _vals;

    function write(uint256 _a) public returns (bool) {
        _vals[_a] = true;
        return _vals[_a];
    }

    function read(uint256 _b) public view returns (bool) {
        return _vals[_b];
    }
}
```

However, right now I'd want A to execute B's methods in the context of A itself, And the following code actually sorta works

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract A {

    address _sub = address(B);

    function write(uint256 _a) public returns (bool, bytes memory) {
        (bool x, bytes memory y) = _sub.delegatecall(msg.data);
        return (x, y);
    }

    function read(uint256 _b) public returns (bool, bytes memory) {
        (bool x, bytes memory y) = _sub.delegatecall(msg.data);
        return (x, y);
    }
}
```

The problem is, the read function in A cannot be declared as view-type, and despite it is calling a view-type function in contract B and doesn't modify anything on the chain, I somehow have to pay gas for it.

Since there's a staticcall() function as a view-type compatible version for the call() function, is there anything similar for the delegatecall() function, or if there's some way so that I can let A execute B's method to read some data stored in A's context without having to pay gas?

Comment: I got the exact same question.